# createSnapshot does not throw exception when run against inactive replica volume

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When createSnapshot() is called against a volume that is a replica volume and is in 'Inactive' state, I was hoping it would thrown some exception. But it does not. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Yep it is an issue, but when you perform a failover all the snapshots from the active volume should be syncronized to the inactive volume and all snapshots in the active volume should be replicated to the inactive volume, anyway I am going to report the issue.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for confirming that this is an issue. 
The problem I have is, 
I want to call createSnapshot() and then go in a loop to check when the new snapshot shows up (with getManualSnapshots). So, if createSnapshot() doesn't report an error when it should, I might jsut waste time in the loop that follows, waiting for a snapshot to show up.